# id's on list are not pulling into new list

Tags: apex, failing-tests

I am running into an issue with my method for test where I insert contact records that are in a list and then try to pull the id's to associate it with a different list.

When I do my debug for the `Contact__c` which should be updated with `sr.Contact__c = conts[i].id;` it is pulling in a null value.

If I insert the list for contacts the id's should be associated with the list that I am then pulling the id's from correct?

```
    public with sharing class CC_UnitTestUtil {

    static Database.DMLOptions dml = new Database.DMLOptions();

    public static void createCustomSetting(String Area) {
        // P Sutherland Area Added for Trigger 
        CC_Area_to_Process__c cca = new CC_Area_to_Process__c(Name=Area,TimeZoneSidKey__c='America/Phoenix');
        upsert cca;
    }

    public static list<Sale_Related_Contact__c> createSaleRelatedContact(Id saleId,  list<String> types){
        boolean dmActive = Utils.duplicateMgmtActive('Contact');        
        dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.allowSave = true;
        Account a = new Account(Name = 'TestAcct');
        if (dmActive)
            database.insert(a, dml);
        else
            insert a;
        SuperUserAccount__c sua = new SuperUserAccount__c(AccountID__c = a.Id, Name='Contact1');
        try{insert sua;}catch(Exception e){}
        list<Contact> conts = new list<Contact>();
        for(Integer i=0;i<types.size();i++){
            Contact c = new Contact(LastName=types[i], FirstName=types[i], Email='test@test.com', AccountId= a.id, Related_Company__c= a.Id);
            if ( types[i] == 'Design Studio' || types[i] == 'Additional Meritage Employee')    
                c.User_ID__c = UserInfo.getUserId();
            conts.add(c);
            system.debug('@-@ User id '+ c.User_ID__c);
        }

        if (conts.size() > 0){insert conts;}

        List<Database.SaveResult> res = Database.insert(conts, false);

        // Iterate through each returned result
        for (Database.SaveResult sr : res) {
            if (sr.isSuccess()) {
                // Operation was successful, so get the ID of the record that was processed
                System.debug('@-@ Successfully inserted contact. Contact ID: ' + sr.getId());
            }
            else {
                // Operation failed, so get all errors                
                for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
                    System.debug('@-@ The following error has occurred.');                    
                    System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ':@-@  ' + err.getMessage());
                    System.debug('@-@ Contact fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());
                }
            }
        }

        system.debug('@-@ dmActive before insert ' + dmActive);
        system.debug('@-@ contact List after insert ' + conts);
        system.debug('@-@ contact id after insert ' + conts[0].id);

        list<Sale_Related_Contact__c>  src = new list<Sale_Related_Contact__c> ();

        for(Integer i=0;i<types.size();i++){
            Sale_Related_Contact__c sr = new Sale_Related_Contact__c();
            sr.Sale__c = saleId;
            sr.Type__c = types[i];
            sr.Company_Name__c = a.id;
            sr.Contact__c = conts[i].Id;
            src.add(sr);
            system.debug('@-@ ids for SRC ' + sr.Contact__c);
        }

        system.debug('@-@ size = ' + src.size());
        if(src.size()>0){
            insert src;
        }
        return src;
    }
    public static List<Sale_Related_Contact__c> createSaleRelatedContactMonterey(Id saleId,  List<String> types){
        boolean dmActive = Utils.duplicateMgmtActive('Contact');        
        dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.allowSave = true;        
        Account a = new Account(Name = 'TestAcct');
        if (dmActive)
            database.insert(a, dml);
        else
            insert a;
        SuperUserAccount__c sua = new SuperUserAccount__c(AccountID__c = a.Id, Name='Contact1M');
        insert sua;
        list<Contact> conts = new list<Contact>();
        for(Integer i=0;i<types.size();i++){
            Contact c = new Contact(LastName=types[0], FirstName='John', Email='test2346234@test.com', AccountId= a.id, Related_Company__c= a.Id);    
            conts.add(c);
        }
        if (dmActive)
            database.insert(conts, dml);
        else
            insert conts;
        list<Sale_Related_Contact__c>  src = new list<Sale_Related_Contact__c> ();

        for(Integer i=0;i<types.size();i++){
            Sale_Related_Contact__c sr = new Sale_Related_Contact__c();
            sr.Sale__c = saleId;
            sr.Type__c = types[i];
            sr.Company_Name__c = a.id;
            sr.Contact__c = conts[i].Id;
            src.add(sr);
        }
        if(src.size()>0){
            insert src;
        }
        return src;
    }
    // create sale
    public static list<Sale__c> createSale(List<Lot__c> lots, List<Plan__c> plans, Id primarySalesAssociate,  List<Opportunity__c> opps) {

        list<Sale__c> sales = new list<Sale__c>();

        for ( Integer i=0; i < opps.size(); i++ ) {
            Sale__c s = new Sale__c();
            s.Opportunity__c = opps[i].Id;
            s.Plan__c = plans[i].Id;
            s.Lot__c = lots[i].id;
            s.Swing__c ='Right';
            s.Customer_Contract_First_Name__c = opps[i].Customer_Name__r.FirstName;
            s.Customer_Contract_Last_Name__c = opps[i].Customer_Name__r.LastName;
            s.Customer_Home_Phone_Number__c = opps[i].Customer_Name__r.Phone;
            s.Customer_Email_Address__c = opps[i].Customer_Name__r.PersonEmail;
            s.Customer_Name_Lookup__c = opps[i].Customer_Name__c;
           // s.Approval_Status__c = 'Submitted';
            s.Approval_Type__c = 'Sale';
            s.Primary_Sales_Associate__c = primarySalesAssociate;
            sales.add(s);
        }
        insert sales;
        return sales;
    }
    // create lot
    public static list<Lot__c> createLot(String comId, Integer howMany) {
        list<Lot__c> lots = new list<Lot__c>();
        for ( Integer i = 0; i < howMany; i++ ) {
             Lot__c li = new Lot__c();
             li.Community__c = comID;
             li.Lot_Number__c = string.valueof(i);
             li.Lot_Address__c = '300 Chicago';
             li.City__c = 'Chicago';
             li.State__c = 'IL';
             li.Postal_Zip_Code__c = '60657';
             li.Status__c = 'Available';
             li.Base_House_Price__c = i;
             li.Lot_Premium__c = i; 
             lots.add(li);
        }
        insert lots;
        return lots;
    }
    // create oppotunities
    public static list<Opportunity__c> createOpportunity(String comId, List<Account> accts) {

        list<Opportunity__c> opps = new list<Opportunity__c>();

        Opportunity__c opp = new Opportunity__c();
        for ( Integer i=0; i < accts.size(); i++ ) {
            opp = new Opportunity__c();
            opp.Community__c = comid;
            opp.Customer_Name__c = accts[i].Id;
            opp.Opportunity_Status__c = 'Active';
            opp.Customer_Status__c = 'A-Prospect';
            opp.Realtor_Representing__c = 'No'; 
            opp.How_did_you_learn_about_Meritage_Homes__c = 'Realtor';
            opp.Web_Lead__c = true;
            opps.add(opp);
        }
        insert opps;
        return opps;
    }
    public static Id personAccountRecTypeId; 
    // create accounts
    public static list<Account> createAccount(Integer howMany)  {
        list<Account> accts = new list<Account>();
        for ( Integer i=0; i < howMany; i++ ) {
            Account a = new Account();
            a.FirstName = 'Tester';
            a.LastName = 'TestCust'+ String.valueOf(i);
            a.PersonEmail = String.valueOf(i)+'7s@mh.com';
            accts.add(a);
        }
        insert accts;
        return accts;
    }
    // create accounts monterey
    public static list<Account> createAccountMonterey(Integer howMany)  {
        list<Account> accts = new list<Account>();
        for ( Integer i=0; i < howMany; i++ ) {
            Account a = new Account();
            a.FirstName = 'Tester';
            a.LastName = 'Monterey'+ String.valueOf(i);
            a.PersonEmail = String.valueOf(i)+'7s@mh.com';
            accts.add(a);
        }
        insert accts;
        return accts;
    }
    // create plan
    public static list<Plan__c> createPlan(String comId, Integer howMany, String status) {
        list<Plan__c> complans = new list<Plan__c>();
        for ( Integer i = 0; i < howMany; i++ ) {
             Plan__c pi = new Plan__c();
             pi.Community__c = comId;
             pi.Amount_Base_Price__c = i;
             pi.Square_Feet__c = i;
             pi.Plan_Number__c = '900' + string.valueof(i);
             pi.Elevation__c = string.valueof(i);
             pi.Status__c = status;
             complans.add(pi);
        }
        insert complans;
        return complans;
    } 


    // create community 
    public static Community__c createCommunity(String dId) {

        Community_Sheet__c cs = createCommunitySheet(dID);

        Community__c comm = new Community__c();
        comm.Name = 'Test Comm';
        comm.Status__c = 'Active';
        comm.Division__c = dID;
        comm.Maximum_Incentive__c = 0;
        comm.Area__c = '900';
        comm.Community_Number__c = 'Tes';
        comm.Phase__c = '000';
        comm.Community_Demographic_Information__c = cs.id;
        insert comm;
        return comm;
    }

    // create monterey community 
    public static Community__c createCommunityMonterey(String dId) {

        Community_Sheet__c cs = createCommunitySheet(dID);

        Community__c comm = new Community__c();
        comm.Brand__c = 'Monterey Homes';
        comm.Name = 'Test Monterey Comm';
        comm.Status__c = 'Active';
        comm.Division__c = dID;
        comm.Maximum_Incentive__c = 0;
        comm.Area__c = '900';
        comm.Community_Number__c = 'TestM';
        comm.Phase__c = '000';
        comm.Community_Demographic_Information__c = cs.id;
        insert comm;
        return comm;
    }

    // create community sheet
    public static Community_Sheet__c createCommunitySheet(String dId){
        Community_Sheet__c cs = new Community_Sheet__c();
        cs.Division__c = dId;
        cs.Status__c = 'Active';
        cs.Marketing_Name__c = 'Tes Com S';
        insert cs;
        return cs;
    }    
    // create division
     public static Division__c createDivision() {
        Division__c div = new Division__c(Name='test div',JDE_Division_Key__c = 'Tes',status__c='Active');
        insert div;
        return div;
    }

    // create division monterey
     public static Division__c createDivisionMonterey() {
        Division__c div = new Division__c(Name='test div 1',JDE_Division_Key__c = 'Tee',status__c='Active');
        insert div;
        return div;
    }

    public static Id profileId;
    // create buyer users
    public static List<User> createUsers(Integer howMany,String profileName){
         String type; 
         if(profileId == null){
            profileId = CC_Constants.BuyersProfileId;
            type = 'com';
         } 

         list<User> listOfUsers = new list<User>();

         for (Integer i = 0; i < howMany; i++){
             User u = new User(alias = 'u' + type +i , email='testtest@test.com',
                emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='Test' + type +i, languagelocalekey='en_US',
                localesidkey='en_US', profileid = profileId, 
                timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', username='test@testtest.com.' + type + i);

             listOfUsers.add(u);
         }
         insert listOfUsers;
     return listOfUsers;
    }

    public static List<User> createDesignerUsers(Integer howMany, String profileName) {

        Profile p = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Name = :profileName LIMIT 1];

        list<User> listOfUsers = new list<User>();

        for (Integer i = 0; i < howMany; i++){
             User u = new User(alias = 'u'  +i , email='testtest@test.com',
                emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='Test' +i, languagelocalekey='en_US',
                localesidkey='en_US', profileid = p.Id, dsfs__DSProSFUsername__c = 'testing',
                timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', username='test@testtest.com.' + i);     

             listOfUsers.add(u);
        }
        insert listOfUsers;
        return listOfUsers;
    }
    }
```

```
public with sharing class ContactFunctions {

public static void UpdateParentAccountID (Contact[] records){
    //List<User> usrLst; // to assign OSC
    //User oscUsr;
    // Get the Contact AccountId from the custom setting vs the hard coded way 360vantage did it.
    System.debug('XXXXXXX Contact records equals   ' + records);
    String AccountId = SuperUserAccount__c.getValues('Contact').AccountID__c;
    for ( Contact c: records) {
        if ( !c.IsPersonAccount ) {
            if ( c.Related_Company__c != null )
                c.AccountID = c.Related_Company__c;
            else
                c.AccountID = AccountId;                    
        }
    }   
}
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming `Database.insert()` isn't populating the ids as you would expect.  Also, I don't see a `@isTest` on the method so this doesn't look like a normal unit test environment

Comment: This is part of a bigger test class. is Database.insert() not the correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: I updated the post to show the entire class. This method is just a creation method for test. When I debug the list it gives me the list for contacts after the database.insert() is followed. Then when I debug for the id's after the insert if gives me null values for them.

Comment: Are duplicate rules active in your org for Contact?

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because you are using the `Database.insert()` method with `DMLOptions`. The DMLOptions object contains a property called `optAllOrNone`. By default which is set to `false`.

According to documentation.

> If `optAllOrNone` is set to `true`, all changes are rolled back if any
>   record causes errors. The default for this property is false and
>   successfully processed records are committed while records with errors
>   aren't.

So as by default `optAllOrNone` is false, your transaction will not fail if one or a few records from your contact list `conts` is failed to insert due to some validation or a duplication rule. All the records that do not have any issues will be saved to the database others are not. So when you are referring them in a list, the records failed to save to the database will not have the 'Id'.

Let us see an example here.

```
Contact con = new Contact(lastname = 'test');
Contact con2 = new Contact();// fails to insert
Database.DMLOptions dml = new Database.DMLOptions();
Database.SaveResult[] sr= database.insert(new List<contact>{con, con2}, dml);
system.debug('con ' + con.Id);
system.debug('con2 ' + con2.Id);
```

This gives me null for `con2.Id` because I have missed the required field here, which causes DML to fail. See the debug logs below.

[image]

**So, you need to handle this condition, by adding a null check to the contact Id field.**

[DMLOptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database_dmloptions.htm)

[Database.insert](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm)

Comment: Thanks @rahul gawale for the information on this. So are you referring to me putting an if null on 'sr.Contact__c = conts[i].Id;'? I ask because our validation is that the sales related contact needs to have a contact associated with it.

Comment: I also ran the debug logs on this for my org. 

USER_DEBUG [44]|DEBUG|@-@ contact id after insert (Contact:{LastName=Lender, FirstName=Lender, Email=test@test.com, AccountId=0010v00000UH719AAD, Related_Company__c=0010v00000UH719AAD, Relationship__c=Referral}, Contact:{LastName=Primary Title Company, FirstName=Primary Title Company, Email=test@test.com, AccountId=0010v00000UH719AAD, Related_Company__c=0010v00000UH719AAD, Relationship__c=Referral}, Contact:{LastName=Design Studio, FirstName=Design Studio, Email=test@test.com, AccountId=0010v00000UH719AAD, Related_Com

Comment: `USER_DEBUG [45]|DEBUG|@-@ contact id 1 after insert null
    USER_DEBUG [45]|DEBUG|@-@ contact id 2 after insert null
    USER_DEBUG [45]|DEBUG|@-@ contact id 3 after insert null
    USER_DEBUG [58]|DEBUG|@-@ ids for SRC null
    USER_DEBUG [58]|DEBUG|@-@ ids for SRC null
    USER_DEBUG [58]|DEBUG|@-@ ids for SRC null
    USER_DEBUG [61]|DEBUG|@-@ size = 3`

Comment: try debugging database.saveresult, may be you need to resolve the issues for contacts.

Comment: I updated the insert for conts with adding a size NPE check and I get an error

Comment: USER_DEBUG [15]|DEBUG|XXXXXXX Contact records equals   (Contact:{Id=null, IsDeleted=false, MasterRecordId=null, AccountId=0010v00000UH9JXAA1, IsPersonAccount=false, Salutation=null, FirstName=Lender, LastName=Lender, RecordTypeId=012C0000000GAL4IAO, OtherStreet=null, OtherCity=null, OtherState=null, OtherPostalCode=null, OtherCountry=null, OtherLatitude=null, OtherLongitude=null, OtherGeocodeAccuracy=null, MailingStreet=null, MailingCity=null, MailingState=null, MailingPostalCode=null, MailingCountry=null, MailingLati

Comment: @JoshuaAnderson your contacts are not getting inerted, try debugging like this `Database.SaveResult[] sr = database.insert(a, dml); System.debug('sr =>' + sr);`

Comment: When I put in `Database.SaveResult[] str = database.insert(conts, dml); System.debug('str =>' + str);` we got `USER_DEBUG [45]|DEBUG|str =>(Database.SaveResult[getErrors=(Database.Error[getFields=();getMessage=ContactTrigger: execution of BeforeInsert` is the error that I am getting. Are you assuming that this is just the insert fail on the contact for some reason?

Comment: Yes, absolutely @JoshuaAnderson

Comment: I updated the post again with that method that is being updated on the before insert. It is just pushing the contact to update the parent accountID.

Comment: From the other debugs that I just ran. The ContactFunctions method is failing for `String AccountId = SuperUserAccount__c.getValues('Contact').AccountID__c;` which is what beforeinsert of the contacttrigger is failing. Now the value that superuseraccount__c is looking for is created and when I debug that to see if I have an ID, I am getting one back.